# You are registering the following domain name -> Forward this domain to.. what?

Tags: url, dns, web, domain-name, tld

i've to register a domain but i don't know why they ask me a valid already existing url for my domain.

I'm trying to register www.mysite.tk at [dot.tk](http://my.dot.tk/), should i provide the url of the hosting provider (hostinghood.com)?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support for a domain registrar.

Comment: so should i change tags or delete the question? I think that at stackoverflow some1 could help me. Anyway i think this is a general question, because it is the same for many others domain registrars.

Comment: If you want to forward the domain to another site, then you need to enter a valid URL for that site.  If you don't want to forward the domain to another site, choose a different option.

Comment: i don't want to forward anything because i haven't another website. I just want to create a new one, so, i think that's impossible by this registrar. I'm confused because it's strange that they say "free registration", but you need to already have one.

Comment: Notice that the option to "Forward this domain" is selected.  (Though the screen shot also implies that "Build a new website" is also selected, which seems wrong for radio buttons.)  Again, if you don't want to forward the domain to an existing site, select a different option.  If the registrar *requires* you to have an existing domain, that's something to take up with that registrar and not with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to forward the website, then i think you should check the "Use DNS" options and follow the instructions from there.